# Redirect domain name to ip with port number

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, domain-name, subdomain

I need to redirect a domain name or a subdomain to an ip with port that is the 80 port is already used and assigned to another domain or subdomain name i want to run another server in the same computer or device and redirect to another domain is that possible if yes explain me or redirect me to the respective steps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to _add some punctuation._

Comment: Indeed ^^^ Sentences and paragraphs, please.

Answer (score 1):

> is that possible

It is not possible to achieve with DNS alone. Web browsers do not query DNS for port numbers.

Your main webserver (the one you currently have on port 80 & 443) will need to *proxy* (forward) all requests to the other servers based on domain name (e.g. virtualhost for domain A is served locally, virtualhost for domain B is proxied to another machine, and so on).

Most popular webservers already have the necessary "reverse proxy" functionality built in. Search for `apache reverse proxy` or similar.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.